# ErrorTrigger, TraceFilter, EventHubTrigger, ConsumerGroup not found in latest Azure.EventHubs SDK with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-eventhub

I have recently moved my .NET Framework project to .NET Core 3.1 and I was getting that following attributes were not found: ErrorTrigger, TraceFilter, EventHubTrigger, ConsumerGroup

Can anyone tell me the equivalent of these?

Here are the packages I am using:

    `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.0-beta8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Unity" Version="5.11.6" />`

I am writing a azure webjob which should be triggered from azure event hub.

The way I was using this is:

`ProcessEvent([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")] EventData eventData)`

Comment: Please show us the code, and which nuget packages you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .net core 3.1, You should install [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs, version 4.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs).

After install the nuget package:

[image]

And here are the packages I'm using:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: also can you please share how to do JobHostConfiguration and EventHubConfiguration in Startup.cs for net core 3.1?

Comment: It didnt work for traceFilter either: `` public void HandleException([ErrorTrigger] TraceFilter traceFilter, TextWriter textWriter) ``

Comment: @NandiniSinghal, are you using .net core 3.1 console app? If yes, please follow this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started). And JobHostConfiguration should not work for webjob 3.x.

Comment: For EventData, you should add namespace like this: `using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs`

Comment: It didnt work for ErrorTrigger : `` public void HandleException([ErrorTrigger] TraceFilter traceFilter, TextWriter textWriter) ``

Comment: @NandiniSinghal, there are some changes in webjobs 3.x for ErrorTrigger. Let me check and update you later.

Comment: Another quick q: is ProcessEvent supposed to be implementation of ProcessEventAsync in IEventProcessor?

Comment: @NandiniSinghal, ErrorTrigger is not available in webjob 3.x, see this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/342).

Comment: For the quick question, can you provide more details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213750/discussion-between-nandini-singhal-and-ivan-yang).